# ¿Alguien me podría explicar qué rol tiene el ‘si’ en la conversación a continuación?

Tags: conversación

¿Alguien me podría explicar qué rol tiene el ‘si’ en la conversación a continuación?

-Tengo un hambre que me comería una vaca

-Pero, por favor, **si** acabamos de desayunar

Además de contestar mi pregunta, si podéis corregir mis errores también, lo agradecería mucho! Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para expresar protesta o sorpresa por algo que ha dicho el interlocutor. Según [el punto 1.7.a del artículo sobre «si» del Diccionario Pahnhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=uqFr1XT7vD6KF3oDZL#17a):

> **a)** En oraciones exclamativas, para expresar protesta o sorpresa ante
>   lo dicho por el interlocutor: *—Podías haberme avisado de que hoy venía* 
>   *el inspector. —¡Pero si me acabo de enterar!; —Mi hija se casa este* 
>   *verano. —¡Si es casi una niña!*

En inglés, lo más parecido es el *but*:

> - *But we just had breakfast!*
> - *But I just found out!*
> - *But she's almost a girl!*

Comment: Ah vale, ahora creo que lo entiendo. Como no es muy intuitivo, es muy confuso para un angoparlante. Muchas gracias, lo agradezco mucho!!

Comment: Pues, nunca se puede decir: "Pero me acabo de enterar?" sin el 'si'?

Comment: @FivePoints Se puede, pero la expresión pierde énfasis